# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.reportserver.report.model.TableReportCapitoloPreventivo]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi the java code below generates me the following error it should return a list of models to iterate in spring boot what is it due to and how can I fix it?

**Spring Boot Java Code:**

```
if (typeCalcoloSconto.name().equals("UNICAPERCENTUALE")) {
                        List<TableReportCapitoloPreventivo> listSottoCapitoliStream = repoSottoCapitolo.loadValoriPreventivoUnicaPercentuale(p.getIdPreventivo());
                        listSottoCapitoliStream.forEach(value -> {
                            System.out.println("Value value: " + value.Descrizione);
                        });
                    }

public interface SottoCapitoloRepository extends JpaRepository<SottoCapitolo, Integer> {
    @Query("FROM SottoCapitolo where IdCapitolo=:IdCapitolo")
    List<SottoCapitolo> load(@Param("IdCapitolo") int IdCapitolo);

    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "DECLARE @T AS table( Descrizione varchar(5000), NumeroCapitolo varchar(100), SottoCapitolo1 varchar(5000), SottoCapitolo2 varchar(5000), SottoCapitolo3 varchar(5000), Totale money, DescrizioneEstesa varchar(5000), Images Image, CostoUnitario money, Quantita money, DescrizioneDis varchar(5000),Tipologia varchar(300),PrezzoRiservato money,UM varchar(50)); INSERT INTO @T SELECT Capitolo.Descrizione, Capitolo.NumeroCapitolo,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo1,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo2,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo3, (ROUND(((((ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2)) / 100) * PercentualeMargine) + (ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2))), 2)) * SottoCapitolo.Quantita as Totale ,SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa, SottoCapitolo.Images, ROUND(((((ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2)) / 100) * PercentualeMargine) + (ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2))), 2) as CostoUnitario,SottoCapitolo.Quantita  , CASE when Tipologia='Prezzo' then SottoCapitolo.Descrizione else ''+SottoCapitolo.Codice+ '     ' +SottoCapitolo.Descrizione end as DescrizioneDis,Capitolo.Tipologia,Capitolo.PrezzoRiservato,SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura as UM FROM Capitolo INNER JOIN SottoCapitolo ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo  INNER JOIN Preventivo ON Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  where Preventivo.IdPreventivo =:IdPreventivo ;SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Descrizione ORDER BY a.Descrizione) = 1 THEN a.Descrizione ELSE '' END AS Descrizione, Descrizione as Desc2,a.NumeroCapitolo, a.SottoCapitolo1, a.SottoCapitolo2, a.SottoCapitolo3, a.DescrizioneDis, a.CostoUnitario, a.Quantita, a.Totale AS TotaleCap, a.DescrizioneEstesa, a.Images,a.Tipologia,a.PrezzoRiservato,a.UM FROM(SELECT 1 AS d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Descrizione ORDER BY Descrizione) AS r, Descrizione, NumeroCapitolo, SottoCapitolo1, SottoCapitolo2, SottoCapitolo3, Totale, DescrizioneDis, Images, CostoUnitario, Quantita, DescrizioneEstesa,Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato,UM FROM @T  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 0, Descrizione, NumeroCapitolo, '', '', '', SUM(Totale), '', '', '', '','',Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato,'' FROM @T GROUP BY Descrizione,Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato,NumeroCapitolo) AS a ORDER BY a.Descrizione, a.d ")
    List<TableReportCapitoloPreventivo>loadValoriPreventivoUnicaPercentuale(@Param("IdPreventivo") int IdPreventivo);
}
```

**Error:**

```
    Hibernate: DECLARE @T AS table( Descrizione varchar(5000), NumeroCapitolo varchar(100), SottoCapitolo1 varchar(5000), SottoCapitolo2 varchar(5000), SottoCapitolo3 varchar(5000), Totale money, DescrizioneEstesa varchar(5000), Images Image, CostoUnitario money, Quantita money, DescrizioneDis varchar(5000),Tipologia varchar(300),PrezzoRiservato money,UM varchar(50)); INSERT INTO @T SELECT Capitolo.Descrizione, Capitolo.NumeroCapitolo,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo1,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo2,SottoCapitolo.SottoCapitolo3, (ROUND(((((ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2)) / 100) * PercentualeMargine) + (ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2))), 2)) * SottoCapitolo.Quantita as Totale ,SottoCapitolo.DescrizioneEstesa, SottoCapitolo.Images, ROUND(((((ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2)) / 100) * PercentualeMargine) + (ROUND((((((((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario) / 100) * PercentualeUtile) + (((SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario / 100) * PercentualeSpeseGenerali) + SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario)) * 1), 2))), 2) as CostoUnitario,SottoCapitolo.Quantita  , CASE when Tipologia='Prezzo' then SottoCapitolo.Descrizione else ''+SottoCapitolo.Codice+ '     ' +SottoCapitolo.Descrizione end as DescrizioneDis,Capitolo.Tipologia,Capitolo.PrezzoRiservato,SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura as UM FROM Capitolo INNER JOIN SottoCapitolo ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo = Capitolo.IdCapitolo  INNER JOIN Preventivo ON Preventivo.IdPreventivo = Capitolo.IdPreventivo  where Preventivo.IdPreventivo =? ;SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Descrizione ORDER BY a.Descrizione) = 1 THEN a.Descrizione ELSE '' END AS Descrizione, Descrizione as Desc2,a.NumeroCapitolo, a.SottoCapitolo1, a.SottoCapitolo2, a.SottoCapitolo3, a.DescrizioneDis, a.CostoUnitario, a.Quantita, a.Totale AS TotaleCap, a.DescrizioneEstesa, a.Images,a.Tipologia,a.PrezzoRiservato,a.UM FROM(SELECT 1 AS d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Descrizione ORDER BY Descrizione) AS r, Descrizione, NumeroCapitolo, SottoCapitolo1, SottoCapitolo2, SottoCapitolo3, Totale, DescrizioneDis, Images, CostoUnitario, Quantita, DescrizioneEstesa,Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato,UM FROM @T  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 0, Descrizione, NumeroCapitolo, '', '', '', SUM(Totale), '', '', '', '','',Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato,'' FROM @T GROUP BY 
Descrizione,Tipologia,PrezzoRiservato,NumeroCapitolo) AS a ORDER BY a.Descrizione, a.d 
    Errore durante la stampa del preventivo: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type 

[com.reportserver.report.model.TableReportCapitoloPreventivo] for value '{oppala, oppala, 2, , , , Radio chiave programmabile a 4 canali ARC20 Bentel, 55.0600, 2.0000, 110.1200, Fornitura e programmazione di radio chiave bentel mod. arc20 a 4 canali programmabili indipendenti per sistemi vector rx ., [B@69703345, Prezzo, 0.0000, NR}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.reportserver.report.model.TableReportCapitoloPreventivo]
    2023-05-10 08:14:16.875 ERROR 70424 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```